# Spring Integration XMPP - Unable to send messages to Chat Server if the property autoStartup of XmppConnectionFactoryBean is configured to false

Tags: xmpp, spring-integration

I'm unable to send messages to Chat Server if the property autoStartup of XmppConnectionFactoryBean is configured to false.

All is OK and messages are sent when I'm configure autoStartup = true.

Configure autoStartup = false is useful in order to avoid deployment failure if the ApplicationContext is started when the Chat Server is unreacheable.

The version of Spring Integration that I'm using is 4.1.1-RELEASE

I'm configuring an XMPP Message Outbound Channel Adapter using a Spring ApplicationContext as described in the following code block:

```
    <bean id="my-xmpp-connection" class="org.springframework.integration.xmpp.config.XmppConnectionFactoryBean"> 
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration">
                <constructor-arg value="myHost"/>
                <constructor-arg value="myport"/>
                <constructor-arg value="myService"/>                
                <property name="securityMode" value="disabled" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="user"        value="myUser" />
        <property name="password"    value="myPassword" />
        <property name="autoStartup" value="false" /> 
    </bean>

    <int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter id="my-xmpp-outbound-adapter"
        channel="my-input-channel"
        xmpp-connection="my-xmpp-connection"/>
```

Someone else has noticed the same behavior?

Thank you in advance.
Massimo

Answer (score 1):

From one side, please, take a look to the `SmartLifecycle` JavaDocs and study that it is normal behaviour for components which is based on the `autoStartup=false`. In other words you have just confirmed that `XmppConnectionFactoryBean` works as designed ;-).

Well, let's analize what's going on there!

The `XmppConnectionFactoryBean` produces `XMPPConnection` which isn't workable if you don't call its `connect()`. Exactly this is done by `start()`/`stop()` of that `XmppConnectionFactoryBean` - the `XMPPConnection` lifecycle controller in the Spring's applicationContext.

From other side you have done correct conclusion regarding deployment failures, so on the intuitive level you know what is it and what to expect from it.

To fix your issue you must do something like this manually:

```
&myXmppConnection.start();
```

where `myXmppConnection` is an id of your `XmppConnectionFactoryBean` bean definition, `&` is `BeanFactory#FACTORY_BEAN_`PREFIX`because of`XmppConnectionFactoryBean`. And the finally`start()`which initiates`XMPPConnection.connect()`.

Of course when the `autoStartup=true` that `start()` is done by applicationContext automatically and your `XMPPConnection` tries to connect to the XMPP server just after application start.

Hope I am clear.

Comment: Hi @artem, thanks for your reply.  I solved my issue using your suggestions: I think my solution is not as clean and elegant: I created a ChannelInterceptor to check the connection status and call the start () method of XmppConnectionFactoryBean accordingly.  I can now configure autoStartup=false and open the connection just prior to sending messages.  Thanks a lot.  Massimo

Comment: I doesn't make sense from where you `start()` that component. And I think it is really sounds correct to do that from the `ChannelInterceptor` before sending the message to the adapter. If the answer is appropriate for you, it would be better to mark as accepted to let other community to rely on it.